# TypeScript Build properties panel is disabled

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

The "TypeScript Build" properties panel in the project properties page is disabled so i can not change the values. All the fields are disabled and grayed out. i am not in a "run time" mode of course.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. It was due to a ts config file in the project that was "overriding" the project settings page and effectively locking it. Once I deleted that file, closed and re-opened the project properties, the TypeScript Build page became available.

Comment: This should be marked the answer. The key is to close the solution and reopen to see the options "un-greyed".